# Qt Print Dialog reappears after Print button clicked

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to print a graphic in Qt.

The signals and slots are connected as follows :

```
connectStat = connect(_ui->printButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(doPrint()));
```

and the slot is as follows:

```
...
QGraphicsScene * m_scene;
...
void GraphDrawerWidget::doPrint() {
    QPrinter printer;
    if (QPrintDialog(&printer).exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
         printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Landscape);
       QPainter painter(&printer);
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
        m_scene->render(&painter);
    }
}
```

The Print dialog does appear, and I can get the scene to print by clicking on the Print button. However, after I do this, the print dialog is showed again. It doesn't matter if I click Print, Cancel or the Window X button, it still shows after the click.

Am I possibly connecting the signals/slots wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Found it!
It seems I was doing the connect() in another method called run() (GraphDrawerWidget::run()) which is where I was feeding the data into the Graphic.

This run() got called once for each signal I was adding to the graphic, so the same slot was connected multiple times.

I am now connecting in the constructor and everything works fine.

Comment: Note, the connection type flag [`Qt::UniqueConnection`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) might be useful in cases like this.